# Typo in the question-asking window (on Russian.SE and Spanish.SE as well)

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

The box where you type the title of your question says, "What's your **the** Japanese language question?"
[image: Typo]

Comment: Same issue on [Russian](http://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and [Spanish](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), but not Italian, Chinese, German, or French. Separately, the text in that box for [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) ("What's your learning the English language question?") is wonky as all heck.

Comment: I suspect it used to be "What's your question about the Japanese language?" and then got changed to "What's your the Japanese language question?". On other stack exchanges, this wouldn't be a problem, e.g. "What's your question about programming?" -> "What's your programming question?".

Comment: However, what should it be changed to? "What is your Japanese language question?" makes it sound like asking why the sky is blue in Japanese would be on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done:

[image]